# Error while creating database in master

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Sql server 2008-r2 and connect it using windows authentication.
when i create database then i am getting error

Create database permission denied in database Master

What may be the reason of it and how can it be resolved?

I even forgot the sql server authentication password also to connect it.

Comment: **2008** as in your body, or **2008 R2** as in your tags? Please be consistent! Either update your body or your tags to indicate the same version of SQL Server ....

Answer (score 0):

Go into the master security settings and try to give your user SA permissions.

It may be that your Windows Authentication has security rights, but not create rights.

If that doesn't work, you might have to install a new instance of SSMS and create a linked server to the data that you need.

PS:  This should be a comment, but I can't make comments for another 7 reputation.